# Android - Uploading Image that sits at the public folders

Tags: android, image, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image that not sits under the app folder but at a public folder.

In order to upload the image, I'm using the next code -

```
private String doPicUpload(String path1){

    File file1 = new File(path1);
    String urlString = "http://87.182.1.15/upload_pic.php";
    try {
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
      FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
      MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
      reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
      post.setEntity(reqEntity);     

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      resEntity = response.getEntity();
      final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
      return response_str;
    } catch (Exception ex){
      Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
      String expction = "0";
      return expction;
    }
}
```

Now, When I debug this code it seems to stops at this line -

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

And also the logcat says -

```
03-21 14:13:16.074: E/Debug(26180): error: /file:/storage/emulated/0/MyDir/img_1395403976349.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-21 14:13:16.074: E/Debug(26180): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/MyDir/img_1395403976349.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Now as you can see the path of the image is fine, there's a file like that on device with the same name.

So what am I doing wrong here? 
Should I refer to the MEDIA environment, and if so what should I do?

Thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your manifest file*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And try to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get your file path.
Your path should look like this `/storage/emulated/0/MyDir/img_1395403976349.jpg`